# xpages open pages using [NRIC] Field

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Question here, may i know using this way to open existing document is totally wrong, or i miss out some part?

Cuz currently not be able to open existing document.

Let say i already have the "document" inside with NRIC 851013-13-5125

[image: Index]
[image: Submit]

Below is the code to get DocumentID

```
var vw:notesView = database.getView("Request sort by nric used for docID");
var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getDocumentByKey(document1.getValue("NRIC"), true)
if (doc!=null){
    return doc.getItemValue("docID")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desmond,

beside a HUGE security hole - displaying data based on an NRIC only (which is almost public data, since you use it everywhere to sign up for membership, discount cards etc.

You should change a few things:

- Bind you entry box to a scope variable, not a document, so instead of `document1.getValue("NRIC")` you use `viewScope.NRIC`
- You don't need to go after an item, but use `doc.universalid`, or better have that as a column in the view, so you could use `@DbLookup(....)`
- Even better: you could simply redirect the URL to open `/yourdb.nsf/byNRIC/[S12345678X]` having a view `byNRIC` that is sorted by NRIC and has in the form property the XPage to open

Having said that: PLEASE(!!!) implement proper security. Singapore's legislation is *VERY* specific on data protection. You might want to read up on it here: https://www.pdpc.gov.sg/legislation-and-guidelines/overview

Comment: thanks stwissel, i think i get what you means, Actually i am malaysian, used to attend your workshop for IBM xpages one few year ago...Actually i am planning to create a system for annoymous[anyone] user to request for email. If they already apply the email, user just need to key in his "NRIC" to retrieve his apply form and check the status of his application!

Comment: You still need to secure that properly